# Simulate Xilinx FIR compiler with a COE file using GHDL

Tags: vhdl, ghdl

Neither does not seem to have been asked in any forums I could find, nor could I find how to do this using the GHDL documentation. Apparently I don't have enough reputation to ask a GHDL question on SuperUser(they don't have the tags), so I have to ask here.

I am trying to simulate a DSP core, which contains several self-written vhdl cores as well as a few Xilinx coregen cores using GHDL. I have to admit, that I am fairly new to GHDL, but not new to VHDL. I know the logic of the core and testbench in question is sound, since it simulates well using ISim. The program has its limits however, which is why I want to try GHDL.

However, GHDL does appear to chicken out on simulating a Xilinx FIR compiler, due to a missing Filter file.

I am setting up my simulation environment using the Makefile snippets below

```sh
#GHDL CONFIG
GHDL_CMD    = ghdl
GHDL_FLAGS  = --ieee=synopsys --warn-no-binding

# vhdl filebase
SRCBASE  = ../../../source
ISEBASE  = /opt/Xilinx/14.7/ISE_DS/ISE/vhdl/src

####################
# import all the necessary source files 

# first the external libraries
$(GHDL_CMD) -i $(GHDL_FLAGS)                   --work=unisim        $(ISEBASE)/unisims/{,primitive/}*.vhd
$(GHDL_CMD) -i $(GHDL_FLAGS)                   --work=ieee_proposed $(ISEBASE)/ieee_proposed/*.vhd
$(GHDL_CMD) -i $(GHDL_FLAGS) --warn-no-library --work=xilinxcorelib $(ISEBASE)/XilinxCoreLib/*.vhd

# then the components roughly in the right order
# (the order actually does not matter, since the analysis step generates the correct order)
mkdir work
$(GHDL_CMD) -i $(GHDL_FLAGS) --work=work $(SRCBASE)/coregen/*.vhd
$(GHDL_CMD) -i $(GHDL_FLAGS) --work=work $(SRCBASE)/pcie/pkg_types.vhd  
$(GHDL_CMD) -i $(GHDL_FLAGS) --work=work $(SRCBASE)/DSP/*.vhd
#finally the main testbench (could be merged with the above)
$(GHDL_CMD) -i $(GHDL_FLAGS) dsptop_tb.vhd

########################
# create the Make file (the binding warning is disabled due to the many generates in the xilinx core libraries)
# also analyzes the design and generates the correct hierarchy strcture
$(GHDL_CMD) -m $(GHDL_FLAGS) -fexplicit --work=work dsp_top_tb

# run the stuff
$(GHDL_CMD) -r $(GHDL_FLAGS) -fexplicit --work=work dsp_top_tb
```

as you can tell from the import statements, my source files are actually in a different directory, which does not bother GHDL however.

Up to the last statement, everything runs fine. However, upon running the last command I receive an error :

> endfile with a non-opened file
>
> from: xilinxcorelib.fir_compiler_v6_3(behavioral).fn_read_mif_file at fir_compiler_v6_3.vhd:1648
>
> ghdl:error: error during elaboration

I believe the problem is that my FIR compiler is generated using the Xilinx FIR compiler and uses a COE file to specifiy the filter coefficients. The line where the error occurs actually opens the file specifying the filter coefficients. In the coregen generated VHDL file it is specified here

```
-- Configuration specification
  FOR ALL : wrapped_decimator_7fold USE ENTITY XilinxCoreLib.fir_compiler_v6_3(behavioral)
    GENERIC MAP (
      c_coef_file => "decimator_7fold.mif", -- < Problematic file
```

My question is now : How do I make GHDL look for the file. I already copied it to the folder, where the run command is being run. As far as I can tell, I cannot import non-vhdl files for GHDL to recognize. So how can I simulate the FIR compiler generated filter using GHDL then?

I hope someone knows how to do this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi, Thanks for taking the time.

Comment: As I initially stated, this is not a Makefile, but just the snippets I thought are relevant, as they identify the folder structure and where stuff is as well as how I execute ghdl. 

The C_ELABORATION_DIR is actually a good hint, I missed that. BUT... as I stated at the end, I did try to copy the .mif file to the folder, where ghdl is executed to no avail. I will try to specify that generic directly. 

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@user1155120

Your suggestion was absolutely right. Unfortunately I had more mif files than I was aware of and GHDL did not actually state, which one it was complaining about. I found out by setting the c_elaboration_dir parameter directly and eventually by copying the failing vhd file and inserting a report statement.

In the end the solution I ended up with was copying all mif files to the ghdl execution directoy, i.e. 
`cp $(SRCBASE)/coregen/*.mif ./`
in the Makescript. This solved the problem. Do you want to post your answer so I can accept is as the solution or are you happy with the kudo?

Thanks again!

Comment: This seems more a comment than an answer.

Comment: why? It states the solution to the problem, i.e. copying all the mif files.

Comment: See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). I deferred to the latter link in not answering the question as is. The useful part of your question is the error message containing the file name (found in ISE 14.7 XilinxCoreLib VHDL source). Your issue can't be replicated lacking a [mcve] and can be troubleshot instead.

Comment: VHDL expects user code will report failures. fir_compiler_v6_3.vhd line 1646 uses a file_open that writes to filestatus, of type FILE_OPEN_STATUS (presumably writing NAME_ERROR). It's Xilinx's code, you can blame them. With fir_compiler_v6_3.vhd source you could troubleshoot by reporting filestatus and C_ELABORATION_DIR & C_COEF_FILE (together the pathname) in lieu of a MCVe. VHDL follows the POSIX interface standard including determining the absolute pathname of a file from the current working directory (where ghdl is excecuted).

Comment: Again thank you for taking the time. Your last comment is of course the gory detail of what I did for troubleshooting. But I don't think an answer necessarily should state, HOW I came to find the answer. I also don't think that a verifiable example was necessary in this case, since I was assuming someone with expert knowledge (such as yourself) too look at my (already quite extensive) text and give a hint to solving the problem. Which is what happened, so I believe I supplied enough information to solve the issue. A complete example would have meant posting a complete testbench.

Comment: The thing I actually believe I a missing in my answer is your first and last sentence, which actually explains the internals I am missing. But this is why I asked you to post an answer so I can accept it as the solution. And again: The solution to the problem ( if not copying and modifying the top level coregen vhdl file) is to copy all the mif files to the ghdl execution directory.